# ArgoCD: Multiple sources for a helm chart

Tags: argocd, argo, gitops

Multiple sources for a helm chart: I have configured multiple sources to fetch helm templates from one repo and values from different repo.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: test-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  sources:
    - repoURL: 'https://github.com/org/values-repo.git'
      targetRevision: branch1
      ref: valuesRepo
      helm:
        releaseName: sample-release
    - repoURL: 'https://github.com/org/helm-chart.git' 
      chart: branch1
      targetRevision: 0.1.0
      helm:
        releaseName: sample-release
        valueFiles:
          - $valuesRepo/helm-values/development/sample-values.yaml
  destination:
    name: 'dev-cluster'
    namespace: 'test-ns'
  project: test-project
```

Error:

```
Failed to load target state: failed to generate manifest for source 2 of 2: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = helm pull --destination /tmp/a59cfffe-fe29-4196-90b3-965445e41d68 --version 0.1.1 --username ****** --password ****** --repo https://github.com/org/helm-chart.git charts/test-chart failed exit status 1: Error: looks like "https://github.com/org/helm-chart.git" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://github.com/org/helm-chart.git/index.yaml : 404 Not Found
```

Does multipe sources expects helm-chart only as package? I haven't packaged my helm-charts.

Comment: That's what the error message is saying. You may open a request on ArgoCD GitHub to implement this as a new feature though.

Comment: I'm not sure it's supported in a single source anyway. Do you know it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: test-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  sources:
    - repoURL: 'https://github.com/org/values-repo.git'
      targetRevision: branch1
      ref: valuesRepo
      helm:
        releaseName: sample-release
    - repoURL: 'https://github.com/org/helm-chart.git' 
      path: path_to_your_helm_chart
      targetRevision: git-branch-name
      helm:
        releaseName: sample-release
        valueFiles:
          - $valuesRepo/helm-values/development/sample-values.yaml
  destination:
    name: 'dev-cluster'
    namespace: 'test-ns'
  project: test-project
```

This worked for me, i was specifying `chart:` in the helm-chart reference; it should be `path:` to the helm chart and `targetRevision:` being your git branch.

Comment: Hey there! In my case, I have configured a multisource but I had difference sources one is a chart and the other one where I stored the values.yaml, one is a git repository. Can I use a path in one source? For example, the chart source to specify the path where the application needs search these values?

Comment: @AndresCabrera If i understood your question correct. 
Yeah, you can refer the path of one source in other.

This way i referred in above example!
 - $valuesRepo/helm-values/development/sample-values.yaml